# How to set up a NAS as an FTP server for external acces?

Tags: networking, ftp, nas

I would like to access my files on my NAS through FTP on the internet, by writing my domain name into the internet browser:

```
ftp://username:password@myipadress.com
```

The problem is, I can only do this on my local network with my local ip address:

```
ftp://username:password@192.168.0.12
```

and somewhy with my domain name it is not working.

[I have enabled FTP on my NAS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKIcb.png)

[I have a valid domain name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Xmm.png)

[And I have forwarded port 21.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBf3K.png)

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a firewall blocking the server's connections to the client.  FTP is rather unusual in its design, in that it unnecessarily has the server create new connections to the client.  That didn't seem like it was clearly a bad thing when FTP was designed, but since then, we've started using firewalls and FTP often doesn't work as well with that setup.

The most recommended solution is to not use FTP.  Really, don't.  Not only does it offer challenges with firewalls, but it uses plaintext passwords and the transferred data is unencrypted.  Instead of fussing with using FTP Proxy on each firewall that is involved, focus such efforts on using SFTP or another encrypted instead.  Such protocols don't have the server-initiates-connections-to-client characteristic that, in a modern network design, just seems like weirdness.

Comment: If my answer is a bit too summarized for your likings, and you want more technical detail, the following page describes a work-around (using the "FTP Proxy" feature of a firewall) and discusses why.  https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/ftp.html

Comment: Alright, thanks for the idea. What I basically wanted is a website that can load files from a fileserver with php, and I saw FTP everywhere, thats why I thought that would be appropriate for this job. But I will try ssh and sftp than.